# How to install php-zip extention on scrutinizer-ci?

Tags: php, zip, php-extension, scrutinizer

I tried to use scrutinizer on my repo but return:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/dusk v6.10.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/dusk[v6.10.0].
    - laravel/dusk v6.10.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for php-webdriver/webdriver 1.9.0 -> satisfiable by php-webdriver/webdriver[1.9.0].
    - php-webdriver/webdriver 1.9.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /home/scrutinizer/.phpenv/versions/7.3.15/etc/php.ini
    - /home/scrutinizer/.phpenv/versions/7.3.15/etc/conf.d/pyrus.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

How to install zip extention?

I tried use this config but not working:

```
build:
    nodes:
        analysis:
            dependencies:
                before:
                    - sudo apt-get install -y php-zip
            project_setup:
                override:
                    - 'true'
            tests:
                override:
                    - php-scrutinizer-run
                    -
                        command: phpcs-run
                        use_website_config: true
                    - js-scrutinizer-run
        tests: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct config is:

```
build:
    tests:
        override:
            - true

    nodes:
        tests:
            environment:
                php:
                    version: 7.4
                    pecl_extensions:
                        - zip
        analysis:
            environment:
                php:
                    version: 7.4
                    pecl_extensions:
                        - zip
            tests:
                override: [php-scrutinizer-run]
```

I just copied from [this repo](https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/master/.scrutinizer.yml) (I googled with keyword '.scrutinizer.yml php github zip'), but actually already described on the [official docs](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/guides/php/continuous-integration-deployment) . I was read it but misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Look at this [link](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/guides/install_custom_software)

you should do sth like this if you want to install `abc` for example:

```yaml
build:
  nodes:
    some-node:
      dependencies:
        before:
          - sudo apt-get install -y abc
```

And in your example you can do this:

```yaml
build:
    nodes:
        analysis:
            dependencies:
                before:
                    - sudo apt-get install -y zip unzip php-zip
            project_setup:
                override:
                    - 'true'
            tests:
                override:
                    - php-scrutinizer-run
                    -
                        command: phpcs-run
                        use_website_config: true
                    - js-scrutinizer-run
        tests: true
```

Comment: still package not found

Comment: if you know the php version test sth like this `php7.0-zip` insted of `php-zip` if your php version is `7.0`

Comment: I already tried and still same error, I already answered the correct answer